# Is it better to run simulations on Virtual Machine or Physical Machine?

Tags: java, performance, virtual-machine

I need to run **a lot** of computational simulations for my thesis.
I use Java for my simulations.

I am running Windows 8.1 on my computer. I also have a virtual Ubuntu 14.04 running on VMWare Workstation.

Is it better to run them on virtual machine, or on physical machine.
This question is acutally two folded:

1) Is it better to use Ubuntu or Windows with Java?
2) Is it better to use physical machine or virtual machine?

I could not find a specific answer for this. Does background processes affect the speed of computations more than virtual machine does?

Comment: Define better. If you mean for better performance, then the VM overhead is much larger than any basic background processes(e.g. not rendering a video or playing a game). But if you need more control over the environment where your simulations run (amount of RAM or maybe access to GPU) then VM are better to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Shouldn't matter, since the JVM will not run 'better' on either Linux or Windows. Since you're running Ubuntu on top of Windows, you will loose resources to the host OS. So I'd opt for running it on windows in this scenario.
2) See 1. Why use a virtual machine if the host OS suffices? You'll only loose resources.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it better to use Ubuntu or Windows with Java?

Java should run well on Ubuntu or Windows.

> Is it better to use a physical machine or a virtual machine?

If you have a lot of set up / tear down to do to run each test, a virtual machine might make this easier.  Otherwise, it shouldn't make much difference whether you use a physical machine or a virtual machine.

Since this is for a thesis, you might want to run some tests on your computer to see if there is a major performance difference between Ubuntu or Windows, or a physical machine or a virtual machine.  That way, you can defend your operating system and your virtual / physical decision in your thesis.

Answer (score 0):

1) I doubt there would be any noticeable difference between the two.

2) Depends on a great many things.  Are your simulations heavily disk I/O bound?  If so, a VM might slow them down and having bare metal access might be better.  Are they heavily multithreaded?  Again, a VM might slow them down unless you assign a lot of virtual cores to your VM.  But if they are long running, the ability to suspend and resume the VM in the middle of a run, or take snapshots, might be convenient.

Are they not multithreaded and you have gobs of physical memory?  You might be able to run multiple VMs in parallel and take advantage of multiple processor cores without threading.  There's just too many variables to answer properly.